# gitlab wrong API path

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have nginx config from gitlab provided:

```
  upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
  }

server {
listen 80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
server_name myserver;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
root /home/git/gitlab/public;

 # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
 error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

location / {
# serve static files from defined root folder;.
# @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
}

 # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
location @gitlab {...
```

But I get this message when push:
     open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/api/v3/internal/allowed" failed (2: No such file

It must be "/home/git/gitlab/public/api....
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to `listen *:80;`, restart nginx and see if it persists.

Comment: Thank you!
I've fixed by changing puma config to tcp port 9292 instance use unix socket.

Comment: @monkey remember to accept an answer, or create your own answer if the problem has been solved.